# Checking for multiple substrings in an SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, select

I have a column containing many rows. I am passing into a method a list of values. I wish to return all rows where a substring of this column contains the value I am looking for.

At the moment, I am using `CHARINDEX`to check for a single substring, and appending on `OR CHARINDEX` for every subsequent substring. It's quite messy, as I am sure you can appreciate.

So, at the moment, I have :

```
[Long SQL query]...
queryString.Append(string.Format(" (AND CHARINDEX( '{0}', Table.Column ) > 0 ", ListOfValues[0]));
            foreach (string value in ListOfValues)
            {
                queryString.Append(string.Format("OR CHARINDEX( '{0}', Table.Column ) > 0 ", value));
            }

            queryString.Append(string.Format(")AND CHARINDEX( '{0}', Table.Column) > 0)"));

queryString.Append(")");
```

Is there are less syntactically horrific way to do this ? :)

Thanks

Comment: What is your last Append meant to be doing? It seems to be calling Format with a placeholder but no parameters and I can't work out what it should be doing...

Comment: You should be able to update your post to correct the offending code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, putting string into a SQL query like that, is very risky! If you don't watch out, you're opening your application up for SQL injection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.

And now to the answer:

```
queryString.Append(string.Format(" Table.Column LIKE '%{0}%' ", ListOfValues[0]));
```

To avoid SQL inject, try doing this instead:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParamX","%" + value + "%");
```

As we're doing string comparison here, I can't think of a less messy way of handling it with a SQL server.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question then you can do this on the SQL side more easily.

```
Select MyColumn
From MyTable
Where MyColumn Like '%MySubstringText%'
```

Obviously you would need to create the SQL statement dynamically if your sub string is going to change.

EDIT:

If you've multiple possible substrings then you could populate a table with the list of values and then cross join the two tables and filter using CharIndex.

```
Create table MySubstrings
(
    MySubstring nvarchar(100) not null
)


Select t.MyColumn
From MyTable t, MySubstrings s
Where CharIndex(s.MySubstring, t.MyColumn) > 0
```

The performance may not be great though.

Comment: `Like` is probably less syntactically horrible than `charindex` but you're still going to need the loop and the long set of `this or this or this...`

Comment: I've edited the answer to deal with the multiple values possibility.